# not able to use RSpec expect inside module method

Tags: ruby, rspec, matcher

For one of my RSpec tests I have decided to create a module which contains a method that does the work of verifying actual and expected data. In the below module mytest function has expect matcher.

```
module MyModule
   def self.mytest(actual, expected)
       expect(actual[0]['stats']).to         eq expected[0]['stats']
   end
end
```

The problem I am running into now is when I execute my tests, I get following error

```
NoMethodError:
       undefined method `expect' for ModuleName:Module
       Did you mean?  exec
```

If I use above expect statement outside of the module in my tests it works fine but I want to be able to use it in the method inside the Module. Any idea why I am getting above error and how to resolve it?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is called a custom matcher and the implementation can be found here https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-8/docs/custom-matchers/define-a-custom-matcher#scoped-in-a-module

Comment: thanks @engineersmnky, I will look into this.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you have an error is because `expect` method is defined in [`RSpect::Matchers`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-expectations/RSpec%2FMatchers:expect) module.

In order for methods defined in `MyModule` to have access to `expect` you can include it into rspec config like this:

```rb
RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.include MyModule
end
```

There are also ways to include it in only certain tests/groups. See more details about defining helper methods [here](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/helper-methods/define-helper-methods-in-a-module).